# Border-box not working

Tags: css

I am trying to have my chipped edge match the box size. I tried box-sizing in a number of situations but could not make it work.

```css
.box {
 background-color: #009fbd;
  width: 100%;
}

.box p {
  color: #fff;
}

.chipped-corner:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 15px;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 7px solid #009fbd;
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3">
    <div class="text-center chipped-corner">
      <div class="box">
        <div>
          <p>Pulp Fiction</p>
          <p>Best Movie Ever.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

something like this:

[image]

Comment: what do you mean "have my chipped edge match the box size"? Can you draw a picture of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Agreed please describe the error in a little more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `relative` style to same elem

```css
.box {
 background-color: #009fbd;
  width: 100%;
}

.box p {
  color: #fff;
}
.chipped-corner{
  position: relative;
}
.chipped-corner:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -7px;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 7px solid red;
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3">
    <div class="text-center chipped-corner">
      <div class="box">
        <div>
          <p>Pulp Fiction</p>
          <p>Best Movie Ever.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not with border-box. The issue is with the bootstrap column class you added.

1. It comes with 15px of padding on both sides you need to remove.
2. You need to reset the left position of the `:before` element to 0.

That should get you close to what you're looking for.

Comment: That makes sense. Should I remove the padding from my .box div? or the :before? anyways, I am trying it right now.

Comment: You need to remove it from the `div.col-xs-4.col-sm-3`

Comment: Thanks for your help Ben.